# Как узнать кто и когда добавил строку?

Tags: svn

Есть файл A, в котором появилась определенная строка.
Предположим: `if(1 == 1){...}`

Как с помощью SVN определить кто автор этой строки(чей коммит привнес эту строку) + номер ветки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То же доступно в TotroiseSVN:
Клик правой по файлу в репозитории - Tortoise SVN -> Blame (опции на ваше усмотрение).

Кликнув правой по строке с автором, можно посмотреть лог и предыдущий Blame.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужен [svn blame](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html). Покажет последнего (или не последнего, а на конкретную ревизию) автора для каждой строчки. Пример по ссылке:

```
$ svn blame -x -b http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/readme.txt
     3      sally This is a README file.
     4       jess Don't bother reading it.  The boss is a knucklehead.
     3      sally
```